# How to pass in list of file names to C program

Tags: c, file, arguments

How does one say that their C program should accept a file list?

For example my program `blah` should accept `hello.txt` by the following call in the console:

```
blah hello.txt
```

I am not sure how to parse an argument and label it as a filepath (getopt doesn't talk about this).

Comment: Please go back over your previously asked questions and set them to answered (if possible)

Comment: Are you sure that `hello.txt` is going to be in the same directory as the running directory of `blah` or maybe a user inputs a file stored in a directory not the same as the working directory like this: `blah blahFolder\bla\hello.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getopt()` permutes `argv[]` so that all the non-options are shuffled to the end, so you simply call `getopt()` to parse all the options and then loop through `argv[optind]` up to `argv[argc]`. Those should be your file names, of course you need to check that those files actually exist, etc. C has no primitives for files. Here is some documentation about [getopt()](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html).

Answer (score 0):

Simply parse the argument, and do an open() on path, which is the argument itself, i.e., hello.txt in your case.